# using Mockito and verify failureWriter println

Tags: scala, gatling

I have this function in Scala and that can print data to CSV file (failureWriter) , I want to test this row of code, my test should verify just that **println** was called with the required params and not the writing to the CSV file.
how can I do it?

Thanks!

```scala
  def myFunction (tenantName: String): Unit = {
    println(s"Fetching data for tenant: $tenantName ...")
    lazy val seqOfUsers: Seq[User] = gettingUsers(tenantName)

    val parsedSeqOfUsers = parseTokenExpiration(JobConstants.DAYS_AHEAD_OF_TOKEN_EXPIRATION, seqOfUsers)

    if (parsedSeqOfUsers.nonEmpty) {
      println(s"Found ${parsedSeqOfUsers.size} expiring users! will preform an update")
      parsedSeqOfUsers.foreach(userToUpdate => {
        try {
         if (userToUpdate.accessKeyId.getOrElse("null").equals("null"))
***            failureWriter.println(TokenFailure(userToUpdate.tenantName, userToUpdate.emailAddress, userToUpdate.userId, "Access Key ID is null"))
***         val newToken: String = getNewToken(userToUpdate)
          updateUser(userToUpdate, newToken)
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception => logger.error(e.getMessage)
            println(TokenFailure(userToUpdate.tenantName, userToUpdate.emailAddress, userToUpdate.userId,e.getMessage ))
        }
      }
      )
    }
    else {
      println(s"$tenantName user tokens are up to date")
    }
  }
```

In my test I am getting to this function till this point :

```scala
failureWriter.println(TokenFailure(userToUpdate.tenantName, userToUpdate.emailAddress, userToUpdate.userId, "Access Key ID is null"))
```

this is my tests so far:

```scala
    @Test
    public void WriteFailedUpdateTokensToCsv() {
        Optional<String> optionalEmpty = Optional.empty();
        Option<String> scalaEmpty = OptionConverters.toScala(optionalEmpty);
        Tenant dummyTenant = new Tenant("Test", 90, "test", true,true, null);
        User dummyUser = new Admin("test", "test", 12, "test", "test", "test", "test", "oldToken", scalaEmpty,scalaEmpty);
        tenants.add(dummyTenant);
        users.add(dummyUser);

        Map<String,String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("error","bad request");
        String jsonString = new JSONObject(body)
                .toString();
        HttpResponse<String> fakeResponse = new HttpResponse<>(jsonString, 400, null);


        Mockito.when(httpRequests.getGa(any(),any())).thenReturn(fakeResponse);
        Mockito.when(dataManager.tenantType(any(),anyBoolean())).thenReturn(scala.collection.JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(tenants).asScala().toSeq());
        Mockito.when(dataManager.updateEntity(any())).thenReturn(false);
        Mockito.when(dataManager.getAllUsers(any())).thenReturn(scala.collection.JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(users).asScala().toList());

        // when
        updateTokensJob.start(UpdateTokensJob.listOfTenantTypesInPerf());

//        //then
        Mockito.verify(dataManager, Mockito.times(UpdateTokensJob.listOfTenantTypesInPerf().length())).getAllUsers(dummyTenant.tenantName());

    }
```